# Please suggest topics for Weekly Topic

Tags: discussion

Title is pretty self explanatory, but suggest topics below and vote for topics you'd like to see.

Comment: Have we considered a community blog - the topics listed here would make excellent monthly blog articles without too much extra effort. On security.SE our low effort blog posts are Question of the Week, where we have brief chat about a selected question. They keep interest up while we prepare longer articles. See http://security.blogoverflow.com/tag/qotw/

Comment: We haven't had a weekly topic in a while now - is this still going on?

Comment: Yes, one starting tomorrow!  Just failed with the holidays.

Answer (score 6):

Winter

- How to cope with cold
- How to cope with darkness
- How to cope with winter-specific safety issues: avalanches, weak ice
- Regions suitable for beginners for winter trips
- ...

Answer (score 4):

Health concerns.

- How to prevent illness caused by environment or weather?
- How to treat certain conditions like dysentery, vomiting, or parasites?
- How to prevent or treat extreme temperature related illnesses?
- Packing check list.
- First aid skills.
- Outdoor health insurance.
- Immunizations.
- Fight bug bites.
- What does being prepared mean?

Answer (score 3):

Geocaching

- Preparing and wrapping caches, materials, label templates etc.
- Risks and security while searching outdoor caches
- Legal issues when searching city caches (entering school areas, abandoned buildings etc)
- Local geocaching portals for country [X] (other than geocaching.com)
- Trackables (trackable sites, popularity in country [X], logging etc.)
- Stealh techniquest (preventing cache disclosure)
- Geocaching equipment (devices, batteries, mobile chargers etc.)
- Geocaching software

Answer (score 3):

Navigation techniques

- Using different equipment for navigation (GPS, compass, different kinds of maps)
- Navigating in severe weather conditions (white outs, fog, heavy rain)
- Preventing group members getting lost
- How to recognise when you've "gone wrong" with your navigation, then how to backtrack
- Using the environment to navigate rather than equipment - how to gain bearings with no equipment at all
- Avoiding dangers (such as steep, sheer drops) when navigating in low visibility

Answer (score 2):

The Great Splash

- In short, water based outdoor activities
- Best types of water based transport for different situations
- How to know when a particular stream or river is safe to paddle
- Fishing techniques
- Water based survival techniques (how to right a capsized craft, lifesaving techniques, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Up and away! (Climbing)

- Equipment needed to get started rock climbing / bouldering
- Basic techniques for rock climbing
- Rope selection
- When to retire ropes (UIAA falls, etc.)
- Climbing with a partner
- Multi-day climbing trips (requiring nights spent on the rock)

Answer (score 2):

Nutrition

- Best lightweight calorific food for certain situations
- Foods to avoid eating
- When best to eat in the day
- How to ration food safely and effectively
- Calculating the amount of calories needed per day for a particular task